# How to convert html table to excel with multiple sheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

How can I convert multiple html tables to an excel sheet with multiple worksheets? Could you please help into this.

My example https://jsfiddle.net/kdkd/5p22gdag/

```
        function tablesToExcel() {
        {

            var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
            var textRange; var j = 0;
            tab = document.getElementById('tbl2'); // id of table


            for (j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {
                tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
                //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
            }

            tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
                txtArea1.document.close();
                txtArea1.focus();
                sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
            }
            else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
                sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));


            return (sa);
        }

 }
```

Comment: Have you checked these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636956/how-do-i-export-multiple-html-tables-to-excel and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234448/exporting-html-tables-to-excel-xls-in-a-separate-sheet? they seem to have solutions for this

Comment: Thanks for that. I have checked above given link. One little issue is all HTML table has inserted into one worksheet. ( Multiple worksheet successfully created ) but,

Comment: Here is example what you want..http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/

Comment: I have tried this but my table has inline CSS so its not working.  Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kdkd/qxLn3h86/49/

Comment: awaiting for solution.. Please help

Answer (score 40):

You can do as below : [**Here is Full Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/48/)

**Html** :

```
<table id="tbl1" class="table2excel">
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Available</td>
            <td>Count</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bred</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Butter</td>
            <td>4   </td>
            <td>5   </td>
            <td >6  </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
<hr>

  <table id="tbl2" class="table2excel">
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Available</td>
            <td>Count</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bred</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Butter</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td >16</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


<button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['ProductDay1','ProductDay2'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
      + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
      + '<Styles>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '</Styles>' 
      + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
    , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
    , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
      var ctx = "";
      var workbookXML = "";
      var worksheetsXML = "";
      var rowsXML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
          rowsXML += '<Row>'
          for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
            var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
            var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
            var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
            dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
            var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
            dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
            ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                   , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                   , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                   , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                  };
            rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
          }
          rowsXML += '</Row>'
        }
        ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";
      }

      ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
      workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);



      var link = document.createElement("A");
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
      link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
      link.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  })();
```

Comment: this is pure genius! :-)

Comment: I have tried this but my table has inline CSS so its not working. Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kdkd/qxLn3h86/49/

Comment: This link may be help you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467418/retain-html-table-styling-after-exporting-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Thats file but both code are different, One is for create multiple worksheet and another is for with CSS.. How can i merge ???

Comment: phheww, Not getting solution for the same. Please help

Comment: This is substantially my code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301811/adding-worksheet-to-the-excel-file-using-javascript/26323012#26323012. And no, this will not work with CSS because it is XML and not HTML. If you look at my example, you will see that I use `data-style` attributes to define styles which then correspond with `Style` elements in the XML. All styles must be defined in such `Style` elements.

Comment: I don't know of who is this code, because this code is repeat in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301811/adding-worksheet-to-the-excel-file-using-javascript/26323012#26323012. I copy this same code into a xhtml (JSF 2.2) and I get the next error "The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.". I looked on internet, but I didn't find the solution. If anyone could help me, I will be grateful –

Comment: I've picked this version and took it from here, to make a better version. Most of it is working fine. but I really had to do some heavy changes, including adding some styles. Also, this code blindly trusts whatever input is fed. It is so underperformant. You should save those `tables[i].rows[j].cells[k]` in a variable. Also, storings the length of the pieces in a variable will ease the processing time. I've, so far, made it run in less than 200ms for 2 tables, with over 700 cells.

Comment: This answer is not working in IE 11. Is there any alternative solution for make it work on IE ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ButaniVijay thanks for posting the solution. The code snippet works perfect until the number of rows, in my experiment, exceeds 3407 rows with Chrome. The browser simply complains 'Failed - Network error'. However, Firefox works fine.

Comment: Thank You so much, this solution worked for me. Only I have replaced <?xml version="1.0"?>  with <xml version="1.0">  and removed this line : <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>

Comment: CSS is not getting applied in excel. can you please suggest change in above coding so that table can export with CSS?

Comment: Above code is working on Mozilla and chrome but not working on IE.

Comment: This works only if the table is in the same format as you showed in the fiddle example. If i give a tab or more space inside <td> tag then it corrupts the format in excel..

Comment: what is the XLS version of this format? I want to write more <Style> tags but can't find the specification

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How-to-create-multiple-worksheets-into-a-workbook) is a better solution that supports exporting table in the latest Excel format i.e. xlsx
. The accepted solution would fail in case the total number of rows being exported exceeds 3407 on Chrome.

An example from the link above:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ckj281f/

html

```
<button onclick="saveFile()">Save XLSX file</button>
```

javascript

```
window.saveFile = function saveFile () {
var data1 = [{a:1,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
var data2 = [{a:100,b:10},{a:200,b:20}];
var opts = [{sheetid:'One',header:true},{sheetid:'Two',header:false}];
var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("restest344b.xlsx",?) FROM ?',
                 [opts,[data1,data2]]);
}
```

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Did not find anything on the internet to fix this, so I created my own. This is a working example that creates 2 or more sheets (1 sheet per table) and WORKS PROPERLY. Enjoy! :)

[Run the example in https://jsfiddle.net/xvkt0yw9/](https://jsfiddle.net/xvkt0yw9/)

This is a ~reverse-engineering of **.mht** representation of XLS export (**Web page**).
The sheet name is defined in the **data-SheetName** attribute of each table.
The function can be easily transposed to other programming languages. (It is basically full of **replace me**s)

Also provided inline-style for cell number formating (As text, General, 2 decimal)

**Note**: the cell grid does show regardless of whether you set the option or not...
**Warning** Do not indent the javascript function. (i don't know what happens to the XLS if you do, did not test, did not have to)
Html: (Put the following content inside a **test.html** file and run it in your browser. Click on the button and open the exported Worksheet.xls)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tablesToExcel = (function ($) {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , html_start = `<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">`
    , template_ExcelWorksheet = `<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{SheetName}</x:Name><x:WorksheetSource HRef="sheet{SheetIndex}.htm"/></x:ExcelWorksheet>`
    , template_ListWorksheet = `<o:File HRef="sheet{SheetIndex}.htm"/>`
    , template_HTMLWorksheet = `
------=_NextPart_dummy
Content-Location: sheet{SheetIndex}.htm
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252

` + html_start + `
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <link id="Main-File" rel="Main-File" href="../WorkBook.htm">
    <link rel="File-List" href="filelist.xml">
</head>
<body><table>{SheetContent}</table></body>
</html>`
    , template_WorkBook = `MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Workbook
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_dummy"

------=_NextPart_dummy
Content-Location: WorkBook.htm
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252

` + html_start + `
<head>
<meta name="Excel Workbook Frameset">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<link rel="File-List" href="filelist.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
    <x:ExcelWorksheets>{ExcelWorksheets}</x:ExcelWorksheets>
    <x:ActiveSheet>0</x:ActiveSheet>
 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<frameset>
    <frame src="sheet0.htm" name="frSheet">
    <noframes><body><p>This page uses frames, but your browser does not support them.</p></body></noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
{HTMLWorksheets}
Content-Location: filelist.xml
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

<xml xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <o:MainFile HRef="../WorkBook.htm"/>
    {ListWorksheets}
    <o:File HRef="filelist.xml"/>
</xml>
------=_NextPart_dummy--
`
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (tables, filename) {
        var context_WorkBook = {
            ExcelWorksheets:''
        ,   HTMLWorksheets: ''
        ,   ListWorksheets: ''
        };
        var tables = jQuery(tables);
        $.each(tables,function(SheetIndex){
            var $table = $(this);
            var SheetName = $table.attr('data-SheetName');
            if($.trim(SheetName) === ''){
                SheetName = 'Sheet' + SheetIndex;
            }
            context_WorkBook.ExcelWorksheets += format(template_ExcelWorksheet, {
                SheetIndex: SheetIndex
            ,   SheetName: SheetName
            });
            context_WorkBook.HTMLWorksheets += format(template_HTMLWorksheet, {
                SheetIndex: SheetIndex
            ,   SheetContent: $table.html()
            });
            context_WorkBook.ListWorksheets += format(template_ListWorksheet, {
                SheetIndex: SheetIndex
            });
        });

        var link = document.createElement("A");
        link.href = uri + base64(format(template_WorkBook, context_WorkBook));
        link.download = filename || 'Workbook.xls';
        link.target = '_blank';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="tablesToExcel('#table_1,#table_2', 'WorkSheet.xls');">HTML Tables to XLS sheets</button>
    <table id="table_1" data-SheetName="My custom sheet 1">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <td colspan="4" style="border-color:#fff;">
                    Left info
                </td>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-right" style="border-color:#fff;">
                    Right info
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7" style="border-color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;font-size:2em;" class="text-center">
                    Title
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7" style="border-left-color:#fff; border-right-color:#fff;border-top-color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;font-size:1.5em;" class="text-center">
                    Subtitle
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7" style="border-left-color:#fff;border-right-color:#fff;border-top-color:#fff;height:50px;">
                    Spacer
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="mso-number-format:'\@'">1</td>
                <td style="mso-number-format:'General'">2</td>
                <td style="mso-number-format:'0\.00'">3</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
                <td>info</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="table_2" data-SheetName="My custom worksheet 2">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <td colspan="2" style="border-color:#fff;">
                    Left info 2
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-right" style="border-color:#fff;">
                    Right info 2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="border-color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;font-size:2em;" class="text-center">
                    Title 2
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="border-left-color:#fff; border-right-color:#fff;border-top-color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;font-size:1.5em;" class="text-center">
                    Subtitle 2
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="border-left-color:#fff;border-right-color:#fff;border-top-color:#fff;height:50px;">
                    Spacer 2
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="mso-number-format:'\@'">3</td>
                <td style="mso-number-format:'General'">4</td>
                <td style="mso-number-format:'0\.00'">5</td>
                <td>info2</td>
                <td>info3</td>
                <td>info4</td>
                <td>info5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bhutani Vijay's code works perfectly fine. For IE 11 compatibility I used the Blob object as below:

```js
var tablesToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">' +
    '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>' +
    '<Styles>' +
    '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>' +
    '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>' +
    '</Styles>' +
    '{worksheets}</Workbook>',
    tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>',
    tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
    var ctx = "";
    var workbookXML = "";
    var worksheetsXML = "";
    var rowsXML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
      if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
      for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
        rowsXML += '<Row>'
        for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
          var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
          var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
          var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
          dataValue = (dataValue) ? dataValue : tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
          var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
          dataFormula = (dataFormula) ? dataFormula : (appname == 'Calc' && dataType == 'DateTime') ? dataValue : null;
          ctx = {
            attributeStyleID: (dataStyle == 'Currency' || dataStyle == 'Date') ? ' ss:StyleID="' + dataStyle + '"' : '',
            nameType: (dataType == 'Number' || dataType == 'DateTime' || dataType == 'Boolean' || dataType == 'Error') ? dataType : 'String',
            data: (dataFormula) ? '' : dataValue,
            attributeFormula: (dataFormula) ? ' ss:Formula="' + dataFormula + '"' : ''
          };
          rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
        }
        rowsXML += '</Row>'
      }
      ctx = {
        rows: rowsXML,
        nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i
      };
      worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
      rowsXML = "";
    }

    ctx = {
      created: (new Date()).getTime(),
      worksheets: worksheetsXML
    };
    workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

    var link = document.createElement("A");
    
    // IE 11
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      var blob = new Blob([workbookXML], {
        type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
      });
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'test.xls');
    }
    // Chrome and other browsers
    else {
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
    }

    link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
    link.target = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code for multiple sheets. I am using three tables data for generating excel.
Import library:

import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

```
static doExcel1(tableId1, tableId2, tableId3) {

    let targetTableElm1 = document.getElementById(tableId1);
    let targetTableElm2 = document.getElementById(tableId2);
    let targetTableElm3 = document.getElementById(tableId3);

    const wb = { SheetNames: [], Sheets: {} };
    var ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(targetTableElm1).Sheets.Sheet1;
    wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet1"); wb.Sheets["Sheet1"] = ws1;

    var ws2 = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(targetTableElm2).Sheets.Sheet1;
    wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet2"); wb.Sheets["Sheet2"] = ws2;

    var ws3 = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(targetTableElm3).Sheets.Sheet1;
    wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet3"); wb.Sheets["Sheet3"] = ws3;
    console.log(ws1); console.log(ws2); console.log(ws3); console.log(wb);
    const blob = new Blob([this.s2ab(XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' }))], {
      type: "application/octet-stream"
    });
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'demo.xlsx';

    document.body.appendChild(link);

    link.click();

    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
  static s2ab(s) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i != s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    return buf;
  }
```

Call using table ids: doExcel1("ExampleTable1","ExampleTable2","ExampleTable3"); on click of button.

**NOTE: Above solution is only for angular if you want use it in node or js then you need to some changes.**

Answer (score 0):

@Butani Vijay

I found one issue with your code.  Though maybe you could argue maybe my source table is not strictly HTML compliant.
Specifically my table is defined similar to

```
    <table id="tbl1">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>E-Mail</th>
                                            <th>Last<br>Login</th>
                                            <th>Suspended</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a target="_new" href="https://xxxxx.zendesk.com/agent/users/378955944453">Joe User</a></td>
                                                <td>JUser@xyz.edu</td>
                                                <td>2020-02-18T16:42:50Z</td>
                                                <td>false</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><b>Totals: </b></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                    </tbody>

    </table>
```

and because of the `<br>` included in  `<th>Last<br>Login</th>` the XML parse indicates it expected a `</br>`.   But why ???    HTML doesnt really have a `</br>`
And because of this although XLS would open there was no data in the spreadsheet, nor were any worksheets defined

But a suitable fix is to change in your javascript of

```
dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
```

to

```
dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerText;
```

Comment: You can't address another answer in your answer. If you found a problem in an existing answer you should post full answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this to give one more option to export in multiple sheet with css.
[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/feuvktj5/4/)

I strucked for more days and found this ways.Hope this may helps for other.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['ProductDay1','ProductDay2'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')

});  
  
  var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>'
      + '   <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">'
    + '     <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">'
      + '           <Author>Qompare</Author>'
      + '           <Created>{created}</Created>'
      + '       </DocumentProperties>'
    + '     <Styles>'
      + '           <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">'
      + '               <NumberFormat ss:Format=""/>'
      + '           </Style>'
      + '           <Style ss:ID="Header">'
      + '               <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>'
    + '             <Borders>'
      + '                   <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Right"/>'
      + '                   <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Left"/>'
      + '                   <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Top"/>'
      + '                   <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Bottom"/>'
    + '             </Borders>'
      + '               <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000"/>'
      + '               <Interior ss:Color="#cccccc" ss:Pattern="Solid" />'
      + '               <NumberFormat/>'
      + '               <Protection/>'
      + '           </Style>'
    + '         <Style ss:ID="Changed">'
      + '               <Borders/>'
      + '               <Font ss:Color="#ff0000"></Font>'
      + '               <Interior ss:Color="#99CC00" ss:Pattern="Solid"></Interior>'
      + '               <NumberFormat/>'
      + '               <Protection/>'
      + '           </Style>'
    + '         <Style ss:ID="Missed">'
      + '               <Borders/>'
      + '               <Font ss:Color="#ff0000"></Font>'
      + '               <Interior ss:Color="#ff0000" ss:Pattern="Solid"></Interior>'
      + '               <NumberFormat/>'
      + '               <Protection/>'
      + '           </Style>'
    + '         <Style ss:ID="Decimals">'
      + '               <NumberFormat ss:Format="Fixed"/>'
      + '           </Style>'    
    + ' </Styles>' 
    + ' {worksheets}'
      + '</Workbook>'
    , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}">'
      + '   <ss:Table>'
      + '       {rows}'
      + '   </ss:Table>'
      + '</Worksheet>'
    , tmplCellXML = '           <ss:Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}>'
      + '               <ss:Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</ss:Data>'
      + '           </ss:Cell>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
      var ctx = "";
      var workbookXML = "";
      var worksheetsXML = "";
      var rowsXML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
          rowsXML += '      <ss:Row>'
          for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
            var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
            var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
            var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
            dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
            if(!isNaN(dataValue)){
                    dataType = 'Number';
                    dataValue = parseFloat(dataValue);
            }
            var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
            dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
            ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Changed' || dataStyle=='Missed'|| dataStyle=='Header')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                   , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                   , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                   , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                  };
            rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
          }
          rowsXML += '      </ss:Row>'
        }
        ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";
      }

      ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
      workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);
      var link = document.createElement("A");
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
      link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
      link.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!--<button  onclick="tablesToExcel( [{ 'sheet': 'firstsheet','tables' : ['tbl1','tbl2']},{ 'sheet': 'secondsheet','tables' : ['tbl5']}], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button> -->
 <!-- button  onclick="">Export to Excel</button> -->
  <button  >Export to Excel</button>
 
<table id="tbl1" class="table2excel">
     <thead>
                    <tr>
                     
                        <th data-style="Header">Product</th>
                        <th data-style="Header">Price</th>
                        <th data-style="Header">Available</th>
                        <th data-style="Header">Count</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-style="Changed">Bred</td>
                        <td data-style="Missed">1
</td>
                        <td>037.57834600204239857
</td>
                        <td data-style="Header">3
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Butter</td>
                        <td>4
</td>
                        <td>5
</td>
                        <td >6
</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<hr>
  
  <table id="tbl2" class="table2excel">
  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Available</th>
                        <th>Count</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bred</td>
                        <td>7.5
</td>
                        <td>8
</td>
                        <td>9
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Butter</td>
                        <td>14
</td>
                        <td>15
</td>
                        <td >16
</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

<table id="joined" class="table2excel">
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function tablesToExcel() {
        {

            var tab_text = document.getElementById("MsoNormalTable").outerHTML;
            var textRange; var j = 0;
            var tab = document.getElementById('MsoNormalTable'); // id of table
            var sa;

            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
            var txt = document.getElementById('txtArea1').contentWindow;
            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                txt.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                txt.document.write(tab_text);
                txt.document.close();
                txt.focus();
                sa = txt.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
            }
            else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
                sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

            return (sa);
        }
 }

<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

It is working with IE7+ fine... :)