# Exporting HTML table with < to Excel using XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, excel

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698796/how-to-convert-html-table-to-excel-with-multiple-sheet) method to export HTML Tables to Excel. However some of the colums in my data have `<` characters. This cause an error when I try to open the file in Excel. Is there some way to ignore these characters or automatically replace them?
Eg:

```
<tr>
<td>Assume A>B</td>
</tr>
```

PS: I already have the html data with `<` character. I am pulling it into a new page, which has a button to export it to excel (using xml format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any solution to the problem mentioned by you. However a workaround can be to write a small data sanitation script using Perl/sed to sanitize your data.
The details of such a script might be taken from [here](https://defuse.ca/html-sanitize.htm).

Comment: Accepting this in absence of a better answer

Answer (score 0):

MS-Excel in general has no problem with the '`<`' character. HTML applications however tend to interprete the '`<`' character as start of an HTML tag.

You can replace the character by `&lt;` during the export and import, and replace this back to '<' when in Excel.

Or you can make sure that text fields are quoted during the process.

Comment: I already have the html data with < character. I am pulling it into a new page, which has a button to export it to excel (using xml format). Edited the Question to add the same info.