# How to export multiple html tables into a single excel worksheet side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have searched google and seen many stackoverflow questions but they had the functions to export multiple html tables to different worksheets in the same excel file.
**But what I want is to export multiple html tables to same worksheet in one excel file side by side.**

I did get a function made by a stackoverflow user which exports multiple tables to different worksheets in the same excel file. I tried to modify it but I am not able to.

the function link: [How to convert html table to excel with multiple sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698796/how-to-convert-html-table-to-excel-with-multiple-sheet)

the one answered by user Butani Vijay

Comment: can anyone ask http://stackoverflow.com/users/2178702/butani-vijay about this problem