# unable to create multiple worksheet in IE+ browser using Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have tried to create multiple worksheets on a button click. I referred to URL mentioned below but i'm unable to get output. This url is working with firefox and chrome. Need to have a solution to get multiple worksheet in excel in IE browser.
thanks in advance.
[How to convert html table to excel with multiple sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698796/how-to-convert-html-table-to-excel-with-multiple-sheet)