# Converting multiple html tables to Excel workbook with multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, html, xml, excel, html-table

I am trying to export multiple tables from a webpage to an Excel workbook with one worksheet per table, has any one managed to do that without needing to transforming the tables into `<rows>` and leveraging the html `<table>` xml, ie inside `<body></body>`.

Currently I am using the below function but, while it does create multiple worksheets, it puts all tables into the first worksheet.

```
 function arrayToExcel(tablesId, filename) {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
  var worksheetTemplate = '<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions><table>{table}</table></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
  var format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  var worksheets = tablesId.map(function(name){
      return format(worksheetTemplate, {worksheet: name});
    }).join('');
  var tables = tablesId.map(function(txt){
      var table = document.getElementById(txt).innerHTML;
      return format(tableTemplate, {table});
    }).join('');
  var formattedXML = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]>'
          +'<xml><o:DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><o:Author>Dominik Dumaine</o:Author><o:Created>'+ (new Date()).getTime() +'</o:Created></o:DocumentProperties>'
          +'<x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>'
          + worksheets
          +'</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body>'
          + tables
          +'</body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
window.location.href = uri + base64(formattedXML);
}
```

used like this `arrayToExcel(["tbl1","tbl2"], "Name of Workbook")`

Has anybody have any suggestion as to how I can amend the above so the different tables go to different worksheets?
The HTML would look like this with additional inline CSS:

```
<table id="tbl1" class="table2excel">
  <tr>
   <td>Product</td>
   <td>Price</td>
   <td>Available</td>
   <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Bred</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Butter</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<hr>
<table id="tbl2" class="table2excel">
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Available</td>
    <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bred</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

N.B.: I have seen Butani Vijay's answer to [How to convert html table to excel with multiple sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698796/how-to-convert-html-table-to-excel-with-multiple-sheet), it does not satisfy my requirements

Answer (score 1):

Install table2excel (you only need the JavaScript file *table2excel.js*):

```
<head><script src="table2excel.js"></script></head>
```

Then the script is:

```
const table1 = document.getElementById('table1');
const table2 = document.getElementById('table2');

document.getElementById('downloadexcel').addEventListener('click', function(){
var table2excel = new Table2Excel();
var tables = [table1,table2];
table2excel.export(tables,'multiple_table');
});
```

If you want to give a name to each sheet, use data-excel-name inside the table tag.
Example:

```
<table id="tabel1" data-excel-name="sheet_name_1">
<table id="tabel2" data-excel-name="sheet_name_2">
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx
The table_to_book and table_to_sheet utility functions take a DOM TABLE element and iterate through the child nodes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only 
answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.