# How to export multiple HTML tables into a single excel file, along with the html table's css/style?

Tags: html, css, excel, html-table

I know there are a lot of this type of question in this site, but i cant find any working solution for this that suit my need. What i need is
 

**1. export multiple html table to excel

2. the table in the excel look exactly like the html table (the css, styling are the same. e.g background-color**)

Is there any way to do this using javascript,etc.?

I found one question for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717451/13670231), but the solution shown there did not solve the css problem. Means that the excel table not have the css like the html table (e.g The excel table doesnt have yellow background eventhough the html table have it)

So basically the main problem is I need the format for the excel file to be same as the html table (css,etc.). Sorry I am new to programming..

Here you can access the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzp7a36c/). 
Or if the link doesnt work, you can just try it below (The codes are taken from the original post , but with an addition of a simple **yellow-colored background** css in it's **tr**)
Thanks in advance.

```js
  var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
      + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
      + '<Styles>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '</Styles>' 
      + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
    , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
    , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
      var ctx = "";
      var workbookXML = "";
      var worksheetsXML = "";
      var rowsXML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
          rowsXML += '<Row>'
          for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
            var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
            var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
            var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
            dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
            var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
            dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
            ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                   , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                   , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                   , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                  };
            rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
          }
          rowsXML += '</Row>'
        }
        ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";
      }

      ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
      workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

console.log(workbookXML);

      var link = document.createElement("A");
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
      link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
      link.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  })();
```

```html
  
  <table id="tbl1" class="table2excel">
                    <tr style="background-color:yellow;">
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Available</td>
                        <td>Count</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bred</td>
                        <td>1
</td>
                        <td>2
</td>
                        <td>3
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Butter</td>
                        <td>4
</td>
                        <td>5
</td>
                        <td >6
</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
<hr>
  
  <table id="tbl2" class="table2excel">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Available</td>
                        <td>Count</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bred</td>
                        <td>7
</td>
                        <td>8
</td>
                        <td>9
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Butter</td>
                        <td>14
</td>
                        <td>15
</td>
                        <td >16
</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


<button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['ProductDay1','ProductDay2'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this. I use the DataTables. Read more here [DataTables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59936/excel-export-create-multiple-sheets)