# How to generate an Excel from HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, excel, typescript

I have tried to generate an Excel using the following function, but the problem is that I sent the function an object that has several properties (HTML template). But for each Key of the object I need to create a Worksheet, but only my function to create one and join the two tables.

My function:

```
GenerateExcel(objeto, titulo) {   
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
        var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head></head><body>{worksheets}</body></html>';
        var worksheetTemplate = '<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{sheetName}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions>{table}</x:ExcelWorksheet>';
        var base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        };
    
        var format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        };
    
        var worksheets = [];
        // var sheetName = "Nombre";
        console.log(objeto);
        Object.keys(objeto).forEach((key) => {
            var sheetName = key;
            var tableHTML = objeto[key];
            console.log(`Nombre de la hoja: ${sheetName}`);
            console.log(`HTML de la tabla: ${tableHTML}`);
            worksheets.push(format(worksheetTemplate, { sheetName: sheetName, table: `<table>${tableHTML}</table>` }));
        });
        console.log(template);
        console.log(worksheetTemplate);
        
    
        var ctx = { worksheets: worksheets.join('') };
    
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = titulo + ".xls";
        link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        link.click();
    }
```

The output:
[image: My excel]

I have been looking for example but i haven't found one for multiple sheets

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037196/4099677